# How can I convert a regular WAV file to a 4bit WAV file using ffmpeg?

Tags: c#, audio, ffmpeg

I have tried something along the lines of

C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg -i "Blip_Select2.wav" -c:a wav -sample_fmt u8 "Blip_Select2_8bit.wav"

but I cannot figure out how to access a 4bit conversion.

I am using the audio for a c# project, 4 bit is sufficient and I prefer wav so I won't have to distribute a possibly restricted usage decoder with my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a heads up that `-b 4` with sox seems to use MS ADPCM codec which encodes the difference between samples using 4 bits. If you want to produce a similar result using ffmpeg you can use:

```sh
ffmpeg -i sound.wav -codec:a adpcm_ms -f wav sound_4bit.wav
```

Comment: No problem. Got me confused also, maybe wav files can have "raw" 4 bit samples per specification but i guess very few implementations supports it

Comment: Yeah, indeed. Though I eventually figured out I cannot really use 4 bit wav files in C# without extra codecs as they are not really recognized. It's a pity. 4 bit 44.100 quality is more than enough for many voice/speech applications and going 4 bit instead of 8 instantly cuts size in half without being lossy.

Comment: Ah :( don't want to depend on any additional codecs? for voice i would probably look into using speex or opus as free alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I did manage to find a solution for this. It's a great command line utility similar to ffmpeg, called **(Sound eXchange) SoX**. It can be found here:

http://sox.sourceforge.net/

The command line that achieves converting to 4 bit wav is this:

```
sox "sound.wav" -b 4 "sound_4bit.wav"
```

It works perfectly and I did not notice any quality drop as the sampling rate is still 44100, while the size drops to 1/4.

An important note. This works well only if your audio is clean and not recorded too loud, such as correctly recorded voice speech (this is what I am using it for), but also works for music as long as it's not too loud.